# Xcode 13.2.1 recompiling complete code every time

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, compiler-optimization

We are facing the recompilation of all the files in our project in the latest Xcode (13, 13.1 & 13.2.1). Every time it's taking almost 3 minutes to run the app even for minor changes on a single file. This was never happened in the Xcode 12.5.1 and the earlier versions. We have set the compilation mode as Incremental.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post this on the Apple forums.

Comment: Tried to clean DerivedData?

Comment: maybe this can help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving-the-speed-of-incremental-builds  or buy an M1 CPU MacBook .